# symfony2 form choice and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, symfony, symfony-forms

When using Entity we can load choices from Entity *via* form field type entity

```
$builder->add('group', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'Fist\CoreBundle\Document\Group',
));
```

but when using mongodb document what is the best way to inject select options from Document?

in my case load all Groups from Group document. Is there better way to do that than passing to form constructor?

Thank you all

Comment: And where exactly is the problem? This should put all Groups to dropdown.

Answer (score 6):

The Doctrine MongoDB ODM equivalent of `EntityType` is `Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle\Form\Type\DocumentType`. `DocumentChoiceList`, `DocumentsToArrayTransformer`, and `DocumentToIdTransformer` are also included in DoctrineMongoDBBundle and parallel their ORM equivalents.

Answer (score 6):

Change `entity` to `document`, and you can just use the shortcut. ex: `FistCoreBundle:Group`

Answer (score 4):

I had to partially stray from Dylan Oliver's answer.

```
Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle\Form\Type\DocumentType
```

could not be found, as of November 2016 DocumentType seems to reside here:

```
Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Form\Type\DocumentType
```

Comment: This is the Symfony4 + Doctrine MongoDB ODM correct answer.