# Symfony2 mongodb bundle document one-to-many forms

Tags: forms, mongodb, symfony, one-to-many, doctrine-odm

I have a problem using forms in Symfony 2 with mongoDB documents.

I'm trying to have a form that will represent my first document (Post) with a relation oneToMany to Tags (reference)

The relation is declared like this :

```
/**
 * @Assert\Collection
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Acme\ManagerBundle\Document\Tags")
 */
protected $tags;
```

A tag has an Id and a Name.

I have tried a lot of things to make it work

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($tag)->add('tags', 'choice', array('choices' => $tags, 'multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true, 'empty_value' => true,  ))
```

The form show the choices but once its submited the form is not valid and keep showing thhis error :

> "The fields "0", "1", "2" were not expected"

I've also tried this : [symfony2 form choice and mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709323/symfony2-form-choice-and-mongodb)

But the use of it is kinda confusing

*UPDATE*

This is what i get after the post is submited :

```
object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)#795 (1) {
  ["_elements":"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(Acme\ManagerBundle\Document\Tags)#723 (2) {
      ["id":protected]=>
      string(24) "4f7a0eb1ecd111b99c3d2f25"
      ["name":protected]=>
      string(6) "Fruits"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Acme\ManagerBundle\Document\Tags)#720 (2) {
      ["id":protected]=>
      string(24) "4f7a0ec7ecd111b99c3d2f26"
      ["name":protected]=>
      string(10) "Vegetables"
    }
  }
}
```

So now i understand why i have "The fields "0", "1", "2" were not expected" but i dont understand why Symfony doesn't process it.

I've been looking a the possible bundles but nothing

I have no idea how to have a nice form that will hydrate my object and the related objects,
does anyone has a solution for this issue or other idea to solve this?

Thanks a bunch !

Comment: What did you try from that question? The answer says to install DoctrineMongoDBBundle and use 'document' instead of 'entity'.

Comment: I tried "choice" and "collection", DoctrineMongoDBBundle is of course already installed and i have use 'document' instead of 'entity' but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data involved I can only make a best guess here.

It feels like your line of code should look something like.

```
$tags = $post->getTags();

$fixedTags = array();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $fixedTags[$tag->getId()] = $tag->getName();
}

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($post)
    ->add(
        'tags', 
        'choice', 
        array(
            'choices' => $fixedTags,
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'empty_value' => true
        )
    );
```

Now I think whats happening is you are getting your $tags data in a form like this.

```
array(0 => (Object)Tag, 1 => (Object)Tag, 2 => (Object)Tag)
```

Where as what you really want is probably like this.

```
array('topic1' => 'Topic 1', 'topic2' => 'Topic 2', 'topic3' => 'Topic 3')
```

If you this isn't the case, reply with some data output and I'm sure we'll be able to help some more.

Comment: Hi Jamie and thank you, i have tried just with this array you gave as a test array('topic1' => 'Topic 1', etc and now the error is : "The fields "0" were not expected"

Comment: Anybody has an idea ? i'm still stuck with this 

    The fields "0" were not expected

And i really don't know how to resolve it !

Thanks

Comment: Looking at your update. the data is in the wrong format still. I'll update my post to how I think your data should look to make it work. I'll point out that I don't use symfony so I'm no expert here. I'm just going by what the documentation says here. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

Comment: It works with a simple array OR with a OneToOne but not with a OneToMany relationship. whatever type of field i try it's always throwing the same error :(. I have also tried this : http://pookey.co.uk/wordpress/archives/286-creating-a-custom-form-field-type-in-symfony-2 (en) and this : http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1082815/php/bibliotheques-frameworks/symfony2/formulaires-liste-deroulante/ (fr) but no positive result...

Comment: I have also tried allowExtraFields =  true; and it resolve the problem but do not save anything in the mongodb document.

Answer (score 0):

A `choice` field won't save by default (although you could manually do it on form submission). You need to look into the `document` type which is admittedly not documented well but it's essentially the same type as `entity` [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

*I didn't see this was from 3 years ago! Well, it's here in case others find this page I guess.*